# How to solve matrix from an optimization problem in MMA?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I want to know whether MMA can solve the optimization problem in matrix form. For example, I want to solve the problem
$$\begin{align}\min ~ &c^Tx\\ s.t. ~ & Ax=b\\&x\ge 0\end{align}$$
In which $c,A,b$ is given. I have used the following command, but it seems not to work:

```
c={1,2,3};
A={{1,2,3},{4,5,-6}};
b={1,1};
Minimize[{c.x,A.x=b,x>=0},x]
```

and I get `Set::write: Tag Dot in {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}.x is Protected.`

#### Update:

- I have changed the known data to make the problem feasible.
- $x>=0$ means that each element of $x$ are $\ge 0$. This is a terminlogy that often used in optimization problems. Sorry for not explain that clearly.

Comment: Read the documentation for `LinearProgramming`

Comment: This: `Minimize[{c.{x1, x2, x3}, A.{x1, x2, x3} == b, 
  x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0 && x3 >= 0}, {x1, x2, x3}]` gives that _"There are no values of {x1,x2,x3} for which the constraints (....) are satisfied"_; but `Minimize[{c.{x1, x2, x3}, A.{x1, x2, x3} == b}, {x1, x2, x3}]` gives `{4, {x1 -> -(3/2), x2 -> 0, x3 -> 11/6}}`.

Comment: @corey979 can I write it in a more compact form? use x instead of writting {x1, x2, x3} many times?

Comment: maple, you can also use a symbolic vector for the variables: `xx = Array[x, 3];
Minimize[{c.xx, A.xx == b, Thread[xx >= 0]}, x]`

Comment: In the current form, the question is not so good. It contains a simple mistake by using `=` and your real question seems to be if you can use a vector `x` instead of manually writing `x1`, ... @Akku14 Whould you go ahead an post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Update with new data and conditions according to @maple.**

```
c = {1, 2, 3};
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, -6}};
b = {1, 1}; x = {x1, x2, x3};


Minimize[{c.x, A.x == b, Thread[x >= 0]}, x]
```

(In your code, you still have the wrong `A.x=b` , which means Set, and not Equal as `A.x==b` .)

```
(*    {1, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1/3, x3 -> 1/9}}   *)
```

But consider, you get not only a single solution point, but a condition for a line in 3-dimensional space, the intersection of two surfaces

```
red = Reduce[A.x == b && c.x == 1 && (And @@ Thread[x >= 0]), x, Reals]

(*  0 <= x1 <= 1/2 && x2 == 1/3 (1 - 2 x1) && x3 == 1/6 (-1 + 4 x1 + 5  x2)  *)

Show[{ContourPlot3D[{x2 == 1/3 (1 - 2 x1), x3 == 1/6 (-1 + 4 x1 + 5 x2)}, 
{x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> x,  
RegionFunction :> Function[Evaluate[x], 0 <= x1 <= 1/2]], 
   Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.05], Point[{0, 1/3, 1/9}]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Akku14, thanks for your detailed answer. I'm sorry for not explain it clearly and I have made some updates of my problem. I would be very appreciate if you could add that constrain. Thanks